# How can i return a list with 1 property not being duplicated?

Tags: c#, list, unique, hashset

I have a method that pulls a list of states and cities from a database. The states are unique, but there can be many cities in that state. What my method currently does is return each state, and city pair as an individual item. What I need it to do is have a state with many cities.

Currently Returns

oh- cincinnati

oh- cleveland

oh- findlay

in- indianapolis

what I need it to Return

oh -cincinnati,cleveland,findlay

in- indianapolis

MODEL

```
public class Location
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }

}
```

REPOSITORY

```
public HashSet<Location> getlocation()
    {
        HashSet<Location> myHashset = new HashSet<Location>();

        const string storedProc = "someProc";

        dynamic locations;


        using (var conn = DbFactory.myConnection())
        {
            locations = conn.Query(storedProc, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        }

        foreach (var location in locations)
        {

                myHashset.Add(new location{State = location.state,City = location.city});


        }
          return myHashset
    }
```

Comment: you could use `GroupBy()` on the `State` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do it

```
var Result = myHashset.GroupBy(r => r.State)
        .Select(g => new Location
        {
            State = g.Key,
            city = String.Join(", ", g.Select(r => r.city))
        });
```

maybe you don't want to store this into a new `Location` object. I'd use a Dictionary

**Update** - Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,string> Result = myHashset.GroupBy(r => r.State)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => String.Join(", ", g.Select(r => r.city)));
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]: After reading your question again, this is probably not, what you are looking for. But if you want a HashSet which only differentiates by State (instead by State and City), then feel free to use this:

**Quick and dirty:**
Override the Location's equal and getHashcode methods:

```
public override bool Equals(Location other)
{
    return this.State.Equals(other.State);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.State.GetHashCode();
}
```

**More clean:**
Use an IEqualityComparer:

```
public class StateComparer : IEqualityComparer<Location>
{
    public bool Equals(Location x, Location y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return Equals(x.State, y.State);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Location obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return 0;

        if (ReferenceEquals(obj.State, null))
            return 0;

        return obj.State.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then create the HashSet with:

```
HashSet<Location> myHashset = new HashSet<Location>(new StateComparer());
```